# jQuery, Quotes, characters etc are breaking my JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using json2.js to create a JSON object which JQUERY posts to the Server. The object looks like:

```
[{"locationID":"16","locationDesc":"XXXX"}, {"locationID":"111","locationDesc":"XXXX"}, {"locationID":"12","locationDesc":"XXXX"}, {"locationID":"11","locationDesc":"XXXX"}]
```

Problem here is that XXXX sometimes contains quotes like "we're'" etc.... How should I handle this? Do you I escape somewhere or encode in some way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to scape single quotes in JSON, you should only care about double quotes.

Here is the syntax diagram of a valid *JSON string*:

[image: JSON string]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/string.gif))</sub>

You can also make sure that your JSON is valid using this [tool](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: is there something in json2 or jquery that will do this for me? escaping?

Comment: Yes, and that something is the JSON encoder. It's not your job to think about it.

Comment: This did not answer the question.